# Delete line (textBox) from file C++

Tags: c++-cli

I enter text into textBox, and when button is clicked how can I delete line(entered in textBox) from file?

My deleting method code:

```
public: System::Void deleteOneRejuser() 
    {
        string fileName = "mainBase/main.txt";
        fstream file;

        file.open(fileName, ios::in);

        char buf[255];
        string text;

        //read all lines in file and write in 'buf'
        while(file.getline(buf,255,'\n'));

        //converting
        text = (const char*) buf;

        //convert textBox text in string    
        System::String^ myString = textBox2->Text;
        string str = msclr::interop::marshal_as< string >( myString);

        int pos = text.find(str);

        if ( pos == (int) string::npos )
            this->label2->Text = "Bad line, not found";

        text.erase( pos, str.size() );

        file.close();

        file.open(fileName, ios::out);
        file << text;
        file.close();
    }
```

VS 2010
Windows Forms

Comment: And what happens with the function you show us? Does it work? Doesn't it work? Is there any errors (compiler or runtime)? If you step through the code line by line in a debugger, does it behave as you expect?

Comment: The compiler does not strive, no errors, but does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reading loop will read all lines, but will discard all but the last line:

```
//read all lines in file and write in 'buf'
while(file.getline(buf,255,'\n'));
```

This is because the `getline` call just overwrites the contents in `buf`, it does not append.

Instead do something like

```
//read all lines in file and append to 'text'
while(file.getline(buf,255,'\n'))
    text += buf;
```

Comment: created a new console project where your algorithm works, but in my opinion still not going to look for bugs, thanks for the help